# Can't get Tabulator to render a table version 4

Tags: tabulator

Never used Tabulator, just down loaded version 4. I read the QuickStart and documentation, but only get a blank screen when running the example script. My pathways are correct and I can run other javascript scripts, so not sure what is wrong. I really like the idea of this interface and will help me keep up a small pharmacy organization website, I support.

Here is my html and script

```js
    <script>
        //create Tabulator on DOM element with id "example-table"
        var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
      height:205, // set height of table (in CSS or here), this enables the Virtual DOM and improves render speed dramatically (can be any valid css height value)
      layout:"fitColumns", //fit columns to width of table (optional)
      columns:[ //Define Table Columns
       {title:"Name", field:"name", width:150},
       {title:"Age", field:"age", align:"left", formatter:"progress"},
       {title:"Favourite Color", field:"col"},
       {title:"Date Of Birth", field:"dob", sorter:"date", align:"center"},
      ],
      rowClick:function(e, row){ //trigger an alert message when the row is clicked
       alert("Row " + row.getData().id + " Clicked!!!!");
      },
        });
    
        //define some sample data
        var tabledata = [
         {id:1, name:"Oli Bob", age:"12", col:"red", dob:""},
         {id:2, name:"Mary May", age:"1", col:"blue", dob:"14/05/1982"},
         {id:3, name:"Christine Lobowski", age:"42", col:"green", dob:"22/05/1982"},
         {id:4, name:"Brendon Philips", age:"125", col:"orange", dob:"01/08/1980"},
         {id:5, name:"Margret Marmajuke", age:"16", col:"yellow", dob:"31/01/1999"},
        ];
        
        //load sample data into the table
    table.setData(tabledata);
    </script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html" />
 <title>Tabulator</title> 
    <link href="css/tabulator.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/tabulator.min.js"></script>
</head>
    <body>
    
    <div id="example-table"></div>
    
    
    
 </body>
</html>
```

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where are you putting your script tags that contain the Tabulator constructor? they should be in the body and under the ***example-table*** div.

Are you getting any warning messages in your browser console?

Comment: What browser are you running your code in? chrome firefox etc?

Comment: Sorry for the post. The example works if I upload the script to my server. It must be my outdated program that will not run the script properly. I am using phpDesigner 8 (last revision 2013). Can you recommend a IDE that does both php and javascript and can run them locally?

Comment: PHP IDEs are generally only designed for previewing HTML but cant run JavaScript. Most developers these days wont run a browser in their IDE, they will instead setup a server on their local machine (apace or IIS for example) and view the content through the browser locally (chrome, firefox, etc), it gives a more realistic representation of the codes functionality. also all major browser now come with a huge array of development tools to make it easier

Comment: Thank you for you help.

Comment: you are welcome, if this helps would you mind marking it as the correct answer to help others. Cheers :)